# Como solucionar este error "Trying to get property 'data' of non-object"

Tags: php, json, api, php7

Tengo un problema que me está creando un **error_log** con la siguiente línea:

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'data' of non-object in /home/view/games.view.php on line 8

Tengo que decir que me muestra el vídeo correctamente, todo perfecto. Igual no tiene importancia, ya que muestra el vídeo en mi sitio y no muestra ningún error en la home, pero, ¿por qué? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? No tengo amplios conocimientos en PHP, y me surgió esta duda. Gracias.

JSON al que realizo la llamada:

```
'data' => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => '40263',
     'title' => '1941 ',
     'featured' => false,
     'height' => 320,
     'width' => 480,
     'orientation' => 'landscape',
     'responsive' => true,
     'rkScore' => 0.860330865608702,
     'rks' => 0.860330865608702,
     'url' => 'https://play.example.xyz/2048/embed?sid=1',
     'categories' => 
    array (
      0 => 'Strategy',
    ),
     'desc_de' => 'Führe deutsche Streitkräfte auf dem Vormarsch nach Osten oder verteidige Mütterchen Russland auf der sowjetischen Seite. Wähle die richtige Kriegsführungstaktik und verdiene dir deine Sporen als genialer Kommandant an der Front in FROZEN FRONT! Erlebe überwältigende Schlachten des 2. Weltkriegs in dem brillanten neuen Militär-Strategie-Simulator von HandyGames™!',
     'size' => 13,
     'approval_date' => '2016-04-25T11:24:26.000Z',
  ),
)
```

Código PHP:

```
$gameID = $_GET['gid'];

$html = file_get_contents("http://card.example?gid=" . $gameID);
$json = json_decode($html);
$game = $json->data;
```

Código PHP en el HTML:

```
<iframe width="1225" height="625" src="<?php echo $game->url; ?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Verifica que te devuelve hacer `var_export($json);`. Si viendo el resultado no sos capaz de resolverlo, [edit] la pregunta y agregarlo

Comment: validación mas que nada, el get contents puede retornar cualquier cosa dependiendo del estado de la red, el servidor etc. no siempre habra un `->data` si es sólo para eso podes convertir el json a un array (2do parametro a true) y con [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) tener unos valores predeterminados, o verificar que `data` existe con [`property_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) o incluso ver si hubo un error en el json con [`json_last_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, con lo devuelto con var_export($json); como dijo @Marcos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás obteniendo correctamente el JSON que mencionas, tu problema se encuentra el `json_decode()`, debido a que por defecto `json_decode()` convierte los JSON a arreglos asociativos si no le pasas un segundo parámetro para indicarle a que lo convierta.

Tu error básicamente dice que no está pudiendo acceder a la propiedad data porque no es un objeto y tú lo estás llamado con `->` como si fuera un objeto.

Si utilizas una de estas 2 líneas:

```
$json = json_decode($html); 
$json = json_decode($html, true);
```

Podrás acceder a la `data` así:

```
$json['data'];
```

Pero si utilizas el segundo parámetro como false:

```
$json = json_decode($html, false);
```

puedes acceder a data así:

```
$json->data;
```

Como la [documentación de json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) lo dice:

Cuando es true, los objects JSON devueltos serán convertidos a array asociativos, cuando es false los objects JSON devueltos serán convertidos a objects. Cuando es null, los objects JSON serán convertidos a array asociativos u objects dependiendo de si JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY es establecida en los flags.

Comment: Mi problema se soluciono con éxito. Mucha sgracias.

Comment: Excelente, un placer.